Scraping a site with embedded Google Maps
I'm taking a look at this site: [redacted]
Is there a way to scrape the red pins on Google Maps? When you click on a pin, you get the name, address, and phone number. Ideally I would like to be able to create a list of the locations.
Is there a way to do this using APIs? I don't see one when I check the network requests.
Or is the only option to use selenium to input various zipcodes and manually scrape the text one by one?

Try this:
import json
import requests
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://silkroadmed.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'script',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
}

params = {
    'callback': 'slw',
    '_': '1716699895443',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://cdn.storelocatorwidgets.com/json/AJ587baQBwcvO8ZBAoQKFx0r5DhPhcub',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
)

data = response.text

# The JSON is wrapped in "slw(...)".
#
data = re.sub("^slw\(|\)$", "", data)

data = json.loads(data)

with open("hospital-locations.json", "wt") as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2)

with open("hospital-locations.csv", "wt") as file:
    file.write("name,lat,lon\n")
    for location in data["stores"]:
        file.write('"%s", %f, %f\n' % (
            location["name"],
            location["data"]["map_lat"],
            location["data"]["map_lng"]
            )
        )

The resulting data looks like:
name,lat,lon
"Aashish P Gupta, MD", 28.087052, -80.613514
"Abdallah Naddaf, MD", 40.866809, -79.880958
"Abindra Sigdel, MD", 38.248064, -85.751044
"Adam D. Levitt, MD", 28.525766, -81.377504
"Adam Keefer, MD", 32.782840, -79.949424
"Adam Ring, MD", 37.489188, -122.224276
"Adel Barkat, MD", 36.147114, -95.967645
"Adnan Rizvi, MD", 47.648101, -117.413493
"Afshin Skibba, MD", 35.936479, -84.010499
"Ahmad Hussain, M.D.", 34.088233, -117.893752

Here are some of the scraped locations plotted from R using {leaflet}.


The full CSV file can be found at https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/05/locations-from-google-map/hospital-locations.csv with code at https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/05/locations-from-google-map/.

Thank you for the help. Is there a way to know which parts of the header or parameters need to be added to the post request? Some just need the JSON payload, but it seems that's not always the case?
